# Getting whole MySQL table into PHP array VS reading row by row

Tags: php, mysql

What are the drawbacks of reading, let's say up to 10000 rows table into PHP array VS reading and processing row by row?

Comment: Maybe you exceed memory limit by loading a table with million of rows into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data doesn't use up all your memory, I'd say there is no point in using arrays. When you send a query to server and get the result, you have the entire result set in memory anyway, just on the libmysql(dll|so) client memory space instead of PHP memory space. Fetching rows from there one by one is quite fast, since libmysql is compiled and highly optimized, while php is an interpreted language. The difference may not be immediately apparent on small results, but on big ones, you will notice.